# NVIDIA GTX 680 GPU BIOS flash failed and card is bricked

Tags: graphics-card, nvidia-graphics-card, firmware

I own NVIDIA GTX 680 GPU and I wanted to flash it’s BIOS because I read that it is possible to flash it to GTX 770. So I downloaded GTX 770 BIOS and read all tutorials. Now all what I got is a bricked GTX 680…

I tried to make DOS-stick to flash it back, but problem is that I can’t see what is really happening when I plug the GPU because it destroys even integrated GPU’s signal. I tried the stick without the GTX and it booted and it says that there is no NVIDIA cards attached which is correct. How can I get my 680 back to alive?

My motherboard is ASUS P8-Z77-V PRO.

EDIT:
I managed to get the card to work. All I have to do is change motherboard to something which doesn't check the gpu and it worked without backup flash, so now I have GTX680 which performance equals to GTX770. Now my question is how do I get this to work with my own mobo? What the heck really. The mobo I managed to get it to work is Asus P8H77-M PRO.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

GPU wasn't bricked at all. My PCs motherboard just recognized that the GPU have different model (GTX770) BIOS on it and refused to start. When I plugged the GPU to my server, there was nothing wrong with it.

I flashed it back to original BIOS and then modded it to match GTX770 specs and everything was alright.

Thanks to all of you for help!

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to see anything (unless things go wrong), just follow instructions.
I once recovered a card in such way, but I used a 4MB PCI card as primary so I could actually see what I'm doing.
Following the re-flash procedure blindly should work...but if something unknown goes wrong it's best that you see what happens.

So if your MB has 2 PCI-E slots, put in another card, if it's old MB with standard PCI, use an ancient PCI card. That will make things significantly easier.

Since a lot of MBs do have 2+ PCI-E x8/16, just borrow a card to use so you can fix your own.

Comment: I don't have another card, that's why use integrated GPU (Intel HD Graphics 3000). I don't even know what is happening when it tries to flash it back because I'm blind.... I followed the instructions, made DOS-stick, configured the autoexec.bat and everything. I know that the USB is being booted but then, nothing. HDD led does nothing and USB-stick doesn't even have one.

Comment: Problem with on-board is that it will auto-off if an external card is inserted. Double-check the .bat file, it's easy to miss-type something there.

Comment: That's not true, it's always on... Before the card was bricked I hot-swapped the cable from GTX to Integrated and it worked. MSI Afterburner and GPU-Z always show that there is two GPU's, GTX and Integrated. Batch file double checked....

Comment: Note that some MBs also allow to simultaneously enable the onboard video and a dedicated video card by selecting the appropriate card connection type, such as PCI,AGP or PCI Express. Doing so allows you to use your onboard VGA while having an external card. Check this maybe you're in luck.

Comment: We commented in the same time. If you can use it to output the display, what error does the .bat file return ? It is it just doing nothing ? "_" line ? In order to follow what it does, put pause after each line inside the .bat, that way you will know where it stops/where it errors.

Comment: I have less than 1 dollar at the moment.... And closest store is way too long from here.  When I plug the GTX to the mobo, there's red led labeled "VGA_LED" which indicates that there is something wrong with the GPU and after that there is no signal even through integrated...

Comment: there is only one command which is "nvflash -4 -5 -6 backup.rom" and when GTX is unplugged it shows error what says something like "NO NVIDIA CARDS" or something like that, so I think the command is working...

Comment: What cable did you switch exactly?

Comment: Run **nvflash --list** to see if the card is detected. It should respond like: **NVIDIA display adapters present in system:<0> NnnE-GTX  [.....]**  That being the detection part,  **nvflash -i[index] -6 romname.rom** is correct syntax where index is **<0>** or the number listed in the list command.

Comment: I switched DVI-cable. And I cannot run nvflash when GTX is installed because it destroys DVI signal from all sources.... GTX unplugged = I can see, GTX plugged = I'm blind.. GTX plugged before flash = I can see through both, GTX and Integrated. Problem is that I really don't know what is happening when GTX is plugged in. Only thing I can see is that error led on motherboard.

Comment: If the MB error LED is on, the system won't get to boot/load the .bat.

Comment: So that means I can't flash the card back, depressing. I didn't know this can even happen.

Comment: I'll try yet to mess with motherboard's bios if I can do something to GPU settings what will allow it to boot. I'll report later if it did or didn't work.

Comment: Try to reset the BIOS, maybe it helps.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/22323/discussion-between-liznet-and-overmind).